# How do I make the eyelashes follow the rig?

Tags: rigging, shape-keys

I joined the eyelashes to mesh to have them blink and had hope it would follow the rig when I rotate the head but sadly could not do it and unsure what can be done here to fix this.

What I did was:
I added shape keys to them after I had joined them to the mesh which is the body and I'm unsure if that was wise because I never parented them to the bones beforehand and wonder if that could part of the reason why I'm having this problem. I really don't know what to do here other than backtrack but not knowing how to do it in the first place would probably not go so well. What can I do?

[image]

Here's the blender upload file:
https://workupload.com/file/XK5Tz5FBENf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parent the eyelashes to the head bone (spine.006), select the eyelashes, go to pose mode, select the head bone, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, this will parent the eyelashes to the spine.006.

Comment: Little late on response I know but thank you so much! This helped!